# How to define scope for specific content-type in KeywordQuery class

Tags: search, keywordquery

I can get results with simple text queries but i need to limit the results for a specific content-type. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a scope in the Search Service Administration based on your content type or add it as a clause to the query i.e.

```
foo AND ContentType:"My Content Type Name"
```

Comment: I have a question related to this: What should i do if i need to add a column of that content type to query?

Comment: that's really a whole other question but check this out: http://sharepointmetadataandclassification.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/using-medata-properties-to-drive-sharepoint-search.html